# Prove $a^2+6a+1\perp 375$ for all $a\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Prove $A=a^2+6a+1\perp 375$ for all $a\in \mathbb{Z}$

I thought to write $375=3\cdot5^2$. So if $A$ is coprime with $3\cdot5^2$ they must share no prime factors.

Then I test if $3$ or $5$ divide $A$ and if they don't then $A$ and $375$ are primes, right?

So i start testing if $3$ divides A, and I make a remainder table in case I need it.
\begin{array}{c||c|} 
 & a & a^2 \\ 
 & 0 & 0   \\ 
 & 1 & 1    \\ 
 & 2 & 1
\end{array}

Then

$$
a^2+6a+1\equiv a^2+1 \pmod 3
$$
And then I divide into 3 cases: $a\equiv0\pmod3$, $a\equiv1\pmod3$ and $a\equiv2\pmod3$. If all those result in $A\not\equiv0\pmod3$ (which actually is what I got), and I do the same for $5$, and I get the same results, I can say for sure that $A\perp 375$ right?

Comment: I have not seen the $\perp$ symbol used for coprimality before(assuming that is what it is). The more common way to write would be $(a^2 + a + 1, 375) = 1$. Your proof seems correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right: to prove that $a^2 + 6a + 1$ and $375$ are coprime (your notation is fine, by the way), you must show that neither $3$ nor $5$ divide $a^2 + 6a + 1$, which is the same as showing that, for all possible values of $a$, 
$$a^2 + 6a + 1 \not\equiv 0 \pmod 3$$
and
$$a^2 + 6a + 1 \not\equiv 0 \pmod 5.$$
For such small moduli, trying all $8$ total possibilities for $a$ (mod $3$) and then (mod $5$) isn't hard.

Comment: Thanks! If I had a much higher modulus,  what could I do to solve it?

Comment: For a large prime modulus $p$, you could use quadratic reciprocity. Completing the square, we see that $a^2 + 6a + 1 = a^2 + 6a + 9 - 9 + 1 = (a+3)^2 - 8$, so that $a^2 + 6a + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ iff $8$ is a square $\pmod p$. For this, you'd compute the Legendre symbol $(8\mid p) = (2\mid p)^3$, and since the symbol is $\pm 1$, this is just $(2\mid p)$, and there's a formula for that! $(2\mid p) = (-1)^{(p^2-1)/8}$.